# Imagick can't convert PDF to JPEG but ImageMagick can

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

First of all, I used ImageMagick in combination with the Imagick PHP5 extension for a while with no issues at all, untill I accidentally removed GhostScript. Since then I'm trying to get it back working again to no avail.

After reinstalling everything, ImageMagick is able to convert PDF to JPEG. However I can't find `gs` in the DELEGATE list when I run `convert -list configure`. Still when I run `convert sample.pdf[1] sample.jpg` it works perfectly. However, when I reinstalled the php5-imagick extension through `sudo apt-get install php5-imagick` it throws an error when I try to convert PDF to images.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for   this image format`upload/guide.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/533.`

It was thrown by the following code:

```
<?php
//header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
$img = new imagick("upload/guide.pdf[1]"); 
$img->setImageFormat("jpg");
echo $img; 
?>
```

I can't see where the problem is, as ImageMagick itself is just working fine I suppose it's Imagick that doesn't interact with ImageMagick well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by not installing Imagick through the Ubuntu repository. When I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove php5-imagick` and tried to install it through pecl, it threw an error and said that Imagick was already installed (which was weird, because I uninstalled it and restarted apache).

So I uninstalled it through `sudo pecl uninstall imagick` and then reinstalled it using `sudo pecl install imagick` and then added `extension=imagick.so` to php.ini, and restarted apache again. Now everything works again. Hopefully this will help someone having the same problem.